# how to add id attribute to uploaded image

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add id attribute to uploaded image how to do that. I tried but didn't get any idea.Any help would be appreciated

.aspx

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="Upload" />   
<hr />
   <asp:Label ID="lblSuccess" runat="server" ForeColor="Green" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

c#

```
 protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + fileName);

            lblSuccess.Text = string.Format("{0} files have been uploaded successfully.", FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);          

        }
    }
```

Comment: What you mean by *id attribute to uploaded image*, please specify

Comment: @un-lucky so that i could to further operation for saving it into oracle db or searching it.

Comment: You need to _add_ that process in your code above. Perhaps persisting the path and filename (a pointer to its location) with some db id and any other meta data your application needs. You decide what process makes sense for you.

Comment: May be this wil help you https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/816150/how-to-upload-a-file-to-a-web-site-by-using-visual-c